# plane generated by n linearly independent n-dimensional vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Prove that the following statement is true.

[image]

I'm not sure whether the term 'linear combination (narrow sense)' is widely used since I'm studying in Korea. 
According to my professor, the term 'linear combination (narrow sense)' means a1x1+a2x2+....+anxn when a1+a2+...+an=1.

Comment: The term "linear combination" is widely used. However, without the restriction $a_1+\cdots +a_n=1.$ I don't know if "narrow sense" is widely used. It's the first time I have read it. However, I am not a native English speaker.